# Crash while using Pyaudio to record audio on Mac M1

Tags: python, apple-m1, pyaudio

After struggling for a long time, I have finally managed to install the Pyaudio library on my MacBook M1. It can play audio files smoothly, but it crashes when I try to record audio. The error message is

```
libc++abi: terminating
[1] 14101 abort python record.py.
```

I've tried reinstalling different versions of Python and Pyaudio, as well as installing them using conda, but none of these approaches have solved the problem.

I couldn't find an official place to report the issue, so I'm turning to this forum for help. I'm wondering if anyone happens to know how to resolve this problem. Thank you in advance.

I am using Python 3.9.16, Pyaudio 0.2.13, and macOS 13.2.
And the test code is from [the official site](https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/):

```
"""PyAudio Example: Record a few seconds of audio and save to a wave file."""

import wave
import sys

import pyaudio

CHUNK = 1024
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 1 if sys.platform == 'darwin' else 2
RATE = 44100
RECORD_SECONDS = 5

with wave.open('output.wav', 'wb') as wf:
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
wf.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
wf.setframerate(RATE)

    stream = p.open(format=FORMAT, channels=CHANNELS, rate=RATE, input=True)
    
    print('Recording...')
    for _ in range(0, RATE // CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS):
        wf.writeframes(stream.read(CHUNK))
    print('Done')
    
    stream.close()
    p.terminate()
```

Comment: Running into that same issue, any updates ?

Comment: haven't found a solution yet

Comment: I'm also running into that issue. For me it seems to work by using the native python implementation from brew with pyaudio installed. But when trying this through a conda environment it's crashing.

Comment: Conda install pyaudio help fixed some of my errors. Maybe give that a shot for ya.